# SSHPass not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, scp, sshpass

I am facing the same issue as on

[sshpass not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502425/sshpass-not-working-properly)

and also not getting exactly what I need to change.. As mentioned in the same link I tried to do so but not getting what content needs to be change..

@Eonasdan : It will be helpful if you can explain

Answer (score 0):

Just download and compile the [latest version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) of `sshpass` and you should be okay. Remember to uninstall the deb first.